# Замена слова JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Есть код в котором при нажатии кнопки, слова "атрибут" заменяются на ***. Что добавить в эту строку, чтобы заменялись "атрибут" и "Атрибут" слова?

```
txt.innerHTML = txt.innerHTML.replace(/атрибут\S*/gm,'***');
```

Comment: `'Атрибут'.replace(/А|атрибут\S*/gm,'***')`

Comment: `'АтРиБут'.replace(/атрибут\S*/gim,'***')`

Comment: Нужно добавить флаг `i`, для работы с независимым регистром.